# how to make container shrink as needed when it's under expaned

Tags: flutter, containers

[image]

```dart
 Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                 ...
                ，
               getStaticTag(job.jobStat.pending.toString(),
                    const Color.fromRGBO(255, 85, 0, 1.0))]

Widget getStaticTag(value, color) {
  return Container(
      // width: 190.0,
      // constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40, maxWidth: 60),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5.0),
      // height: 80.0,
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: color),
      child: Center(
          child: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: HexToColor('ffffff')),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(value),
        ),
      )));
}
```

as the code above ,I layed containers under expanded widget,so the contaners all expanded as  the pics show below. I need to make the container to shrink, make the width as needed, by it's text content. what should I do, did I need to use other widget?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove the center widget from your widget method:

```
Widget getStaticTag(value, color) {
  return Container(
      // width: 190.0,
      // constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 40, maxWidth: 60),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 5.0),
      // height: 80.0,
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: color),
      child: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
        style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
        ),
        child: Text(value),
      ));
}
```

according to document this widget will expand the space as possible
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html